# How can hazelcast store data relationship between objects in its map?

Tags: java, serialization, hazelcast

Let's say,we have the objects below that need to be stored on the hazelcast.

```
    class A implements Serializable{
       public int id;
       public List<B> incomingBs;
       public A(int x){ this.id=x; }
    }

    class B implements Serializable{
       public int id;
       public List<A> outgoingAs;
       public B(int x){ this.id=x; }
    }
    A a1=new A(1);
    A a2=new A(2);
    B b1=new B(1);
    B b2=new B(2);
    a1.incomingBs.add(b1);
    a1.incomingBs.add(b2);
    b1.outgoingAs.add(a1);
    b1.outgoingAs.add(a2);
```

Then I put the `a1` and `b1` up to hazelcast map. How can hazelcast store such a nested structure. If I pull the data:`a1` from hazelcast,can I get the nested `b1`?If so, then I should have the access to `a1` that contains `b1`,then `b1` has `a1`...then.....Is it possible for hazelcast to do serialization job for this endless nesting?Like a infinity recursion..

To make the question much simpler, if I store the data above in the hazelcast map, can I get the original data with relationships which I just pushed?

Comment: I know this is hazelcast related, but if you are going to use this as any type of persistence, might it be easier to use a Graph Database such as Neo4j to store your data and query it?

Comment: but our project has been settled.. it's using mongodb right now and i can change that.. still, the problem has been solved.

Comment: Okay, just thought I'd suggest it. Your use case seems like it'd fit into a Graph well, but I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as everything is Serializable, yes, it works like magic :)

Just use `transient` on fields where this behaviour is not desired.